# "An error occurred during local report processing. Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: ssrs-2012

I am using to generate rdlc report on my windows application. I have the one main report and more than 30 sub reports, which will render based on dataset values. Everything is working fine, but some time i got the following error when try to generate the report.

> An error occurred during local report processing. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This is not all the the times. Sometimes I am getting these errors. I can't even figure it out. It would be great if you help to sort it out.

Thanks,
Thineshbabu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: See proposed duplicate. If after following the advice there closely, you are still unable to solve your problem, post a new question, in which you've provided a good [mcve], along with a precise and detailed explanation of what you've done so far to try to diagnose the exception, what you've learned about the scenario that throws the exception, and what _specifically_ you still need help with

Comment: With subreports, this is usually related to an unexpected value from the dataset.  For example, sometimes this will occur when a necessary value is `NULL` rather than the integer that the subreport was expecting.  As you have 30+ subreports, this could be very time-consuming to track down and it's surely not something SO can help you with.